# How to make a query using dates

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I need to pull from the DB all rows in a day

```
var i_sDate = "2014-06-21"; // (user input)
var startDate = new Date();
var month = parseInt(i_sDate.substr(5,2)) - 1;
var day = i_sDate.substr(8,2);
startDate.setFullYear(i_sDate.substr(0,4), month, day);
startDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

var endDate = new Date();
endDate.setFullYear(i_sDate.substr(0,4), month, day);
endDate.setHours(23, 59, 59, 0);

var query = {start_time:{"$gte": "ISODate('" + startDate.toISOString() + "')", "$lt": "ISODate('" + endDate.toISOString() + "')"}};
var tableInfo = Users_Collection.find(query).fetch();

console.log(query);
```

when I print "query" it looks OK, but I don't get any result at all, I put the same information directly on the DB and I get the expected result. It seems like I'm building the query in the wrong way, any suggestion?????

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should directly use `Date` objects in your query. Try this:

```js
var query = {start_time: {$gte: startDate, $lt: endDate}};
```

It also looks like you were missing a closing `}`.

Comment: I had the closing } (I didn't paste it in here). I tried what you suggested but didn't work. the date object print "Sun Jun 22 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (EDT)" could it be this the problem????

Comment: Dates always print as strings to the console so no this isn't a problem. It may be that you just have the wrong dates, your database doesn't have the right documents, etc. You can always hard-code the dates just to test the query. e.g. `var endDate = new Date('6-22-2014')` or whatever is appropriate in your case.