# How to compare mongodb string date fields

Tags: meteor

In meteor I am trying to return documents from mongo where a purchase_date is after today's date. This is within the context of a aslagle/reactive-table filter function which already knows the key to search on

I am using:

```
            var today = new Date();
            var dd = today.getDate(); 
            var mm = today.getMonth()+1; 
            var yyyy = today.getFullYear(); 
            var fullDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;


           ({"$gte": fullDate})
```

Today is 5/30/15 and the format of the field is the same string 0/00/00 format but I get back everything that has the month greater than 5 rather than month day and year greater than my passed in date. It seems to only be checking the first number (month) then returning everything with a greater month than 5. That also gets me things like 7/20/00 which is in the past and I need all documents with a date after today's date in the future.

How could this get done inside the mongo selector?

Comment: This seems weird... why are you storing your dates as strings and not `Date` objects?

Comment: inherited this project. I am just trying to find a minimum effective dose of code to solve the problem. I have been searching to no avail.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's a rational way to do what you want. Is migrating the data (modifying all documents to contain actual dates) an option for you?

Comment: That is an option however I am not to sure how to go about doing a bulk field modification on all the records. Even if I could simply reverse the order of the string date to yy/mm/dd that would allow my current code to work. Is there a mongo command that can reverse that value in all the documents? Would it be better to change the data type to an actual date object be better? I am new to this so I very much appreciate any advice. I am trying to search on my own but just not coming up with any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend migrating your string-based dates to actual dates. Here's an example of how you could create a migration (assuming `Transactions` is the name of the collection):

```js
Meteor.startup(function() {
  var docs = Transactions.find({}, {fields: {purchase_date: 1}}).fetch();
  _.each(docs, function(doc) {
    var pd = new Date(doc.purchase_date);
    Transactions.update(doc._id, {$set: {purchase_date: pd}});
  });
});
```

If you add that code anywhere under your `server` directory, your migration should happen as soon as the server starts (make sure to remove this code after it has run). I'd also recommend trying this on a backup of the database first to make sure it does what you want.

Alternatively, there is a [migrations package](https://atmospherejs.com/percolate/migrations) which you can use.

After the db has been updated, you can see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874587/how-to-make-a-query-using-dates) for how to query based on a date.

Comment: Ahh worked like a charm! Thank you so much. Next time I will convert date strings to date objects immediately or start with date if starting from scratch.